# How to display the months list from a specific daterange in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Suppose I have a model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
created = model.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
total = models.IntegerField()
```

and my query is:

```
qs= Order.objects.filter(created__range=('2018,11,1','2019,11,1'))
```

I want to see all the months present within the daterange given in the above query in my template...

How to accomplish this in django?

Any idea?

Comment: What should be the output here? An iterable that contains for example `[11, 1, 3,4,7,8]` since there are only orders for this (hypothetical) data?

Comment: This is just for example...I want to display all the month within '2018,11,1' , '2019,11,1'...as given in my query... The output should be like November,December and so on...

Comment: but only for the ones where there are orders?

Comment: No all the months within the date range given...

Comment: Then I don't see why you use a query for this anyway, this has nothing to do with querying.

Comment: The above model and query is just for example...If there is anything...Can you tell me please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to extract `month` from `created` field of each entry in queryset.

```
import datetime

qs= Order.objects.filter(created__range=(datetime.date(2018,11,1),datetime.date(2019,11,1)))

months = []
for order in qs:
  months.append(order.created.month)
  ...
```

`months` will look something like this: `[6, 10, 11, 4, 4, 4, 9, 10, 2, 4, 4, 11, 4]`

If you want your months to be in a different format `[January, May, etc.]`
Look at **DateFormat** paragraph here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2016/08/10/exploring-django-utils-1.html

Comment: @NiladryKar Updated the answer. The problem was in your query. You should use `datetime` to pass dates in right format.

Answer (score 2):

you can do one thing

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dates = ["2014-10-10", "2016-01-07"]
>>> start, end = [datetime.strptime(_, "%Y-%m-%d") for _ in dates]
>>> OrderedDict(((start + timedelta(_)).strftime(r"%b-%y"), None) for _ in 
xrange((end - start).days)).keys()
['Oct-14', 'Nov-14', 'Dec-14', 'Jan-15', 'Feb-15', 'Mar-15', 'Apr-15', 'May-
15', 'Jun-15', 'Jul-15', 'Aug-15', 'Sep-15', 'Oct-15', 'Nov-15', 'Dec-15', 
'Jan-16']
```